# Trouble deploying MRTK3 application on Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, openxr

I recently came across a Microsoft YouTube video on MRTK3 and became very excited about it. I decided to try it out and visited the Microsoft webpage to get started. I followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-overview/test-and-deploy/hololens2-deployment) carefully, but I'm facing difficulties when attempting to deploy the application on Hololens 2.

Set-up:

OS: Windows 10, MR headset: Hololens 2,
Unity version: 2021.3.24f1 LTS or 2020.3.47f1,
Visual studio version: 2019, MRTK 3: cloned from github repo branch mrtk3

**How can I make the sample MRTK3 scene deploy on Hololens 2 using Unity 2021.3.24f1 LTS?**

Although the entire process completes without any errors, whenever I try to launch the application from the Hololens 2, it gets stuck on the loading menu with the four moving spheres and eventually crashes. Initially, I attempted to resolve the issue by switching to Unity 2021.3.21f1 (the original MRTK3 version), but I still encountered the same strange behavior on the Hololens 2.

Then, I tried creating an empty scene and importing MRTK3 following a [different tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-overview/getting-started/setting-up/setup-new-project), but I still experienced the same problem. Feeling desperate, I attempted to run an empty project with a cube and object manipulator using Unity 2020.3.47f1 following this [tutorial](https://localjoost.github.io/How-to-setup-up-MRTK3-to-support-HoloLens-2-and-Quest-2-including-hand-tracking/). Surprisingly, I managed to successfully deploy MRTK3 on the Hololens 2. However, when I tried running the MRTK3 sample scene in Unity 2020.3.47f1, it unsurprisingly did not work, as the documentation states that Unity 2021.3.24f1 is the minimum requirement.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this deployment issue and understanding the compatibility between MRTK3 and different Unity versions.

Thank you!

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I've run into the same issue with MRTK3 and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: have you tried looking into the log file? @dez

Comment: [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-overview/getting-started/setting-up/setup-dev-env) also mentions `Visual Studio 2022` not `2019` ;)